# Show menu entries only for certain user roles

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, visibility, role

I'd like to get to know how I can set menu entries visible or hidden for certain user roles in XAML code? Eg I have "_MenuEntryForADMIN" which should only visible for user role "admin" and "_MenuEntryForAllUsers" should be visible to all users - role "user".

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel>
            <MenuItem Header="_MenuEntryForADMIN">
                <MenuItem Header="_Master1" Click="btnMaster1_Click">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="database.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Master2" Click="btnMaster2_Click">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="database.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_MenuEntryForAllUsers">
                <MenuItem Header="_Normal1" Click="btnNormal1_Click">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="database.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="_Normal2" Click="btnNormal2_Click">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="database.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

The CS-Code contains the information whether a user has the role "admin" or "user" like this:

```
User userObject;

public MainWindow(User userObject)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.userObject = userObject; // this.userObject.Role is "admin" or "user"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF, it is important to 'shape' your data into the correct structure before you try to display it. By this, I mean that you should filter the data, your `MenuItem`s, in your view model or code behind *before* displaying them, rather than trying to filter them in the UI.

So rather than defining them all in XAML, create some custom data type to data bind to the various `MenuItem` properties that you are interested in. Then create a `DataTemplate` and bind a collection of these to the `MenuItem.ItemsSource` property. You can find out how to do that from my answer to the [Dynamically hiding menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362729/dynamically-hiding-menu-items/22364100#22364100) question. In short, it looks something like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameter}"
        Header="{Binding Path=Header}" Visibility="{Binding Visible, Converter={
        BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildMenuItems}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

There are also many examples online of filtering data in collections, so I won't go over all of that here. You can find a short example in the [“Hiding” part of List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326115/hiding-part-of-list/20326785#20326785) question here on Stack Overflow. Basically, you can use LinQ to select just the admin `MenuItem`s something like this:

```
ChildMenuItems = new ObservableCollection<YourCustomDataType>(
    FullCollection.Where(i = i.Role == "admin").ToList());
```